# Jdbc/Jdbctemplate - Preventing creating a database on connect

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbctemplate

I am using JdbcTemplate with SQLite (will be replaced by ms sql server later on)for some local testing.

I want to test that a connection is ok when connecting to a valid datasource BUT I also want to test that I get some exception if I connect to an invalid/non-existent datasource.

My problem:

When connecting to a non-existent datasource, a new database is created by default. How can I prevent this behavior?

Thanks!